# Reset Screen Time with Forgotten Passcode

Tags: ipad, password, screen-time

I have forgotten my passcode for the Screen Time on my iPad, how can I still change the password without wiping the iPad's data? I have searched online but all articles say that there is `Forgot Passcode?` if you have iOS or iPadOS 13.3 or later, but I don't see that option with the newest version. [image: the newest version]How can I still change my passcode?

[image: here is the changing password screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To verify your identity to reset the Screen Time passcode, you log in with your Apple ID.](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT211021) In your screenshot, it says ‘Sign in to iCloud…’ implying it’s not currently logged in. This means you can’t use the ‘forgot passcode’ functionality to reset the Screen Time passcode.